# Stay / Steer clear of someone

Tags: meaning

Imagine a time when a woman tells you "I'm trying to stay clear of you...", may it carry any positive kind of meaning? Or this sentence is just showing that the one saying this phrase is trying not to get close to you and has totally a negative meaning? Or in other words you are annoying...?
I'm asking this question to have a better idea of this phrase and what it really means.

Answer (score 2):

From the way that you posted the question, the term can be generally assumed as negative. Or, I should say, the outcome is positive for one party and negative for the other.

For example:

- You are creepy. So, I want to steer clear of you.
- I am not feeling well. I don’t want you to get sick, also. So, I want to steer clear of you.
- I have a surprise for you. And, it’s hard for me to keep a secret. So, I am going to steer clear of you until I am ready to reveal it.
- You always smell like my favorite cookie, cologne, etc. So, I am going to steer clear of you.

If the outcome is negative for both, it should be pretty self-evident. If the outcome is positive for both, the statement will be said in an obviously facetious or playful manner.